Facebook Business Manager app advanced access permission
we are using an app for Facebook Business Manager that allows us to manipulate users' catalogs, enabling us to dynamically add products to their Meta catalog. We are looking to use the "commerce_account_read_settings" permission to determine which of their catalogs is linked to their store. However, this permission does not provide an option for an advanced access request, which means it can be used only by users within this app. Is there a way to submit an advanced access request for this permission so that we can interact with all users and not just those within our business manager?

Did you ever figure out the issue? Don't see a way to get advanced access to the commerce permissions
